# How can i print float values if they are float, otherwise int?

Tags: python

```
 nums = [20 , 10 , 2 , 1]
 list(map(lambda x: (x / 100) * 50, nums))
```

I want to get 10, 5, 1, 0.5

So, if number becomes float during calculations, i want to get float(in this case 0.5), but if it's it remains integer, I want to get number without '.0' in the end. What's the easiest way to do this in this code structure?

Comment: If you really only want to **print** as in the question title, the `g` format specifier can do that: `[format(num, "g") for num in nums]`. BTW: This `list(map(lambda ...))` can analogously be expressed with a list comprehension as `[num/100*50 for num in nums]`, which makes it a lot easier to read.

Comment: +1 to Jeronimo. Generally, if you want a certain output format, use formatting tools - and not rounding or numeric operations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`is_integer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer) method of floats.

Here using a wrapper function:

```
def downcast(f):
    return int(f) if f.is_integer() else f

list(map(lambda x: downcast((x / 100) * 50), nums))
```

output: `[10, 5, 1, 0.5]`

*Note that this does not change how floating point arithmetic can affect the computation, for instance with `14` as input, this would still yield a `7.000000000000001`, in this case you can first round to the desired precision.*

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to save it into variable, and then check the type of this variable (for example: if type(output) is int... etc)
Hope it helps

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
nums = [20 , 10 , 2 , 1]
res = list(map(lambda x: (x / 100) * 50, nums))
# iterate list and change type to int when necessary - use difference between number and int(number)
res = [int(i) if i-int(i)==0 else i for i in res]
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[10, 5, 1, 0.5]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if this is a good solution but I think this could do the thing:

```py
stuff = [10, 5, 1.5]
for value in stuff:
    if type(value) is int:
        print(value)
        print("done printing integer")

    elif type(value) is float:
        print(value)
        print("done printing float")
```

Output:

```
10
done printing integer
5
done printing integer
1.5
done printing float
```

Comment: In OP's situation, none of the objects will be `int`s - they will be `float`s, just with integer values.